# Diferrence between normalization of a histogram and equalization in image processing

Tags: image-processing

So I know that the two methods aim to change the intensity of the pixels. My question is in which way do they differ?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by normalization of the histogram? Any reference?

Answer (score 1):

*Histogram normalization* is a broad term which could refer to various operations performed on a given distribution and does not necessarily imply that pixel values are changed. There are two normalizations that could be of a particular interest for *histogram equalization*:

- Probability Density Function ([PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)): values across the *y*-axis could be interpreted as the probability of a given event *x* happening.
- Cumulative Density Function ([CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)): given a random variable *X*, values across the *y*-axis could be interpreted as the probability of X taking a value less than or equal to *x*.

*Histogram equalization* is a special case of [*histogram matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching). The idea, as the name suggests, is to match the CDF of the input image to the CDF of a target image. As a result, the color tone of the input image will match the color tone of the target image, but the depicted objects will not change. However, perfectly matching (equalizing) the CDFs of two images is not always possible. You can find a plot which illustrates this process below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is a side-by-side plot of the input and matched images to alleviate comparison.

[image]

I hope my interpretation of your rather vague question is correct and this points you at the right direction. I did not dwell too much into the theory behind the process but you can find plenty of information at the pages I have linked.

Comment: “Histogram equalization” is not the same as “histogram matching”, even though the process is similar if you think of the target histogram as a flat function. “Equalization” means making all gray values equally likely.

Comment: I did read up on that and you are indeed correct. Thank you for the input!